# Django: Count of Group Elements

Tags: django

How can we achieve the following via the Django 1.5 ORM:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date, 'IW/YYYY') week_year, COUNT(*) FROM entries GROUP BY week_year;
```

EDIT: cf. [Follow up: Count of Group Elements With Joins in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081183/follow-up-count-of-group-elements-with-joins-in-django) in case you need a join.

Comment: Start reading this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/ and then post here what have you tried.

Comment: We have tried annotate and extra to add week_year. But then, count is not allowed to use that annotated/extra field.

Comment: AFAIK, aggregate reduces the result to a single value. However, here we would like to retrieve the counts for all groups in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something like this recently.

You need to add your `week_year` column via Django's `extra`, then you can use that column in the `values` method.

...it's not obvious but if you then use `annotate` Django will `GROUP BY` all of the fields mentioned in the `values` clause (as described in the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values)

So your code should look like:

```
Entry.objects.extra(select={'week_year': "TO_CHAR(date, 'IW/YYYY')"}).values('week_year').annotate(Count('id'))
```

Comment: Interesting. We tried values as well but we used Count('week_year') not Count('id'). I will come back to you within a minute.

Comment: Django ORM has a bunch of corner cases I guess, not always clear what will work and what won't... you should be able to `Count(...)` any field on the model, doesn't have to be in `values`... I guess you want to choose a field like `id` though where every row is sure to have a value for it

Comment: We did Count('week_year') because we thought that is what we count over.

Comment: it can be anything that's not NULL for the rows you want to count... it's a shame Django doesn't support `Count('*')` like you'd often do in SQL

Comment: Exactly. That is what we discussed right now. Actually, we only want to count the number of entries in a group; not a specific field.

Comment: yes, it's the count of non-NULL values for that field for each row that then gets aggregated in the GROUP BY